# What is the first number in SharePoint Document ID's

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-id, document-center

In SharePoint 2013 I have set up Document ID's for my document libraries. Here is an example of one of the ID's. KBTEST-45-24. Im wonder what the first number relates to. I know that the last number, 24, relates to the documents ID within the Library.

Is the 45 the ID of the library itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes 45 is the ID of the list that the document was first created, and the second number is the ID of the item in that list.

The prefix can be specified per site collection and can be changed from the Document ID Settings page.

More details can be read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2011/10/12/document-id-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)